# Why didn't Giorno heal Polnareff's body and restore his soul to the body?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Golden Wind*, we know that Giorno can heal people by restoring parts of bodies to people. We have seen that he can heal a body so much that Bucciarati's soul, instead of moving on to the afterlife, instead stays in his body. We saw that Giorno healed his own body and jumped right back in after Narancia's death.

Now Polnareff, when we last saw him, was in the body of Coco Jumbo. Because Polnareff's soul did not go to the afterlife, he was stuck in the turtle.

Why then didn't Giorno go to Polnareff's body and heal it, then stick Polnareff's soul back into the body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not addressed canonically as far as I'm aware but I can think of at least two possible reasons:

1. It's too risky: Giorno was able to heal his own body and transfer his consciousness back because he used his own stand to do so. Either Gold Experience Requiem can't transfer a second party's soul between bodies or they aren't willing to risk the possibility that Polnareff's soul would vanish in the attempt
2. It's a temporary solution: As we saw with Bucciarati, Gold Experience can't completely reverse death, just temporarily bind the soul to the body as it decays. Given the choice between this and staying a turtle, Polnareff may have chosen the later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think about it, you are right, Giorno healed his dead body which was an "empty shell" and then got back into it.

Since Polnareff's soul was still alive, he definitely could have done the same. But in part V, there are just too many things that don't make sense, it's just how it is for the story.

Comment: As the other answer stated, it's just temporary.
Also, Polnareff probably wants to just relax in a turtle after all the drama with SC and GW.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear. The only reason bucciarati could pilot his body was because he was fated to die by rolling stones, in a normal case scenario it would be the same outcome as what it was with Josuke and Okuyasu

Comment: This does not address the question and has no supporting evidance. If possible, try to provide facts and sources and if you just want to provide additional information, use comments to do so.

Answer (score -2):

On personal thought, if Polnareff is stuck in a turtle, why not use the solution he did with Bucciarati?

For me, I imagine in my head Giorno will put the turtle on top of Polnareff's chest then heal Polnareff's body. After that, he may be free to go in inside of his body and gain conciseness. This is the pros-and-cons:

- Pro: Giorno may also be able to heal his legs
- Con: It is only a temporary solution
- Pro: He can't feel pain whatsoever and it is good since a small cut down affects him anymore